# Follow Dockerfile Instructions Manually

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I would like to install a software on my host by manually **following a reference installation in a Dockerfile**.

I cannot share the Dockerfile itself unfortunately, but [here](https://github.com/blang/latex-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile.basic) is an example that looks similar.

Is there any resource that explains how to translate commands from a Dockerfile to commands I can run in my terminal?

Details:

- The Dockerfile relies on Ubuntu, and my host also runs Ubuntu (same version)
- The resource I am looking for should discuss caveats like using sudo, handling environment variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not a reference, but...
Nothing complex about your example. If you shell into our compatible host, probably also sudo to root, you should be able to run any commands found after a **RUN**
command in the Dockerfile.

Environmental variables may require an **export** command to get them to be active. e.g.

export NEW_VARIABLE=variableValue